# Raster Dataset Misaligning in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.6, raster-dataset

We have an ArcSDE Raster Dataset of aerial imagery covering a County. A little while back the dataset somehow got tweaked to where it doesn't align correctly anymore.  It is in the NAD83 StatePlane coordinate system.

We could georeference the image but we're not sure how it got misaligned in the first place, therefore, perhaps the solution is something other than georeferencing?

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

[image]

Comment: What is the projection for the line layer ?

Comment: The lines are parcel polygons and are the same coordinate system, NAD83 StatePlane US Feet

Comment: Ok Have you inform the GIS Department about this issue ?

Comment: We don' have a GIS Dept.  IT maintains the database and servers but we are responsible for the data.

Comment: Ok it doesn't sound too good.  Is the parcel polygons a part of SDE ?

Comment: Yes, parcels are also part of SDE.  The parcels are correct.  If I add other data (SDE or not), the are all OK, just the raster is off.

Comment: Yeah this is something you have to address to the IT Dept and let them know.

Comment: I would check your origin point for your base map and your raster are the same.

Comment: I checked and all those parameters are the same, including the latitude of origin & central meridian.

Comment: I can't tell from the image how far off the raster is. How far is it? The parcel sizes look good, so probably still in US feet.

Comment: It is off by about 3 miles.

Comment: "A little while back the dataset somehow got tweaked" - is there some reason why it is not possible to undo this tweak?

Comment: This is an SDE raster dataset, I'm not sure how it was tweaked and/or how to undo it.

Comment: The raster probably had a transformation applied and the transformation needs to be deleted.  While ArcGIS help says this cannot be done in a geodatabase raster, I believe there is a way to do so using the RDBM tools.

Answer (score 2):

[@Steve's comment about the transformation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326403/raster-dataset-misalignment-arcgis#comment533916_326403) might work, but In my experience 3 mi discrepancy seems like an awful lot for a datum transform issue.

What I suspect happened is someone used the georeferencing tools to rereference the image accidentally. This is fairly easy to do if your not careful and forget to select the correct target image in the georeferencing toolbar.

IF the dataset is archived in the sde or you have access to a backup from before the change, I would go back in time and grab the old version of either the SDE or the [archived imagery](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/working-with-historical-versions.htm) and replace the imagery dataset. [Here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/dataset-internal-tables.htm) is a reference on what tables you would need to grab from the backup.

As an aside, storing imagery data in an SDE is not a recommended workflow anymore. ESRI would prefer you to create Mosaic Datasets and store in FGDB and then serve the data out via an imagery server or internally just connect to a dedicated imagery datastore.